# App can neither be installed on android nor IOS

Tags: codenameone

First I send an IOS build to the buildserver (I configured correctly). The result was:

I can install the App on an IPhone 4, but not on an IPhone 6 or an IPad 4 (All three devices are registered) (no build server error, it loads the app and then tells "could not be installed")

After that I send an Android build. I tried to download it to my Samsung Galaxy s3 mini, but it failed again. Similar exception: "App was not installed" with no further explanation.

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:**
- The IXXX devices were registered correctly in the IOS profile
- There are no exceptions on the build server
- The app runs without any problems in the simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons for things like that and unfortunately neither Google nor Apple nor MS provide any form of decent error messages...

9 times out of 10 this is caused because you already have an app with the same package name and a different certificate already installed. Unfortunately there is no easy way to find that other app.

In some cases this is caused on iOS because people take UDID from an app instead of using itunes. Apps don't give you the right UDID.

Comment: why does it run on an iPhone 4 then? And in case of the package name, how much do those need to differ? There is another app already installed.

The installed one has a package name `com.companyname.demo` and the second one `com.companyname.taskmanagement`. could this really be the problem?

Comment: That should work fine. Did you use the certificate wizard to generate the provisioning? If you regenerated the certificate you might have invalidated the old app. If you have a Mac connect it to the device during install and open the console on xcode to inspect the error messages. Sometimes the problem can be inferred from that.

Comment: Yes, i used the cw for the provisioning. The app that does not work is not the old one, but the new one. Could an invalid "old" app be the problem to a non-installing "new" app? And what can be the problem with android? I have a mac here. I will test later

Comment: You can connect Android with a cable and DDMS to see similar error messages in the console. Look in the iOS settings in the IDE and make sure you didn't check push by accident or maybe selected tablet only or some other setting.